# 'src' attribute inside html video tag

Tags: html, html5-video, multiple-browsers

I want to use short video tag format like

```
<video src="path" controls></video>
```

And [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_src.asp) in w3school says:

> To make it work in all browsers - use `<source>` elements inside the `<video>` element.

But as far as I can see my browsers handle short syntax very good (I have `Google Chrome` and `Firefox`). So should I be worried about any possible issues with short video tag notation?

Comment: Test on all browsers you are concerned about...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to IE and Safari also as to apple mobile devices so I can't test it against _any_ possible browsers.

Comment: What I mean is... what browsers are you supporting? What is your specification??

Comment: [http://caniuse.com/#feat=ogg-vorbis](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ogg-vorbis). You were just lucky testing it on these browsers, @valentjedi

Comment: The thing not in `ogg` format, but in short tag syntax. I especially care about safari and IE (starts with 9 version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source` part is about making it compatible with all browsers by including alternative formats for browsers that could not support *the* format specified in `src`.

In example: If you tried to play an `.ogg` file in IE12, which doesn't support `.ogg` with the code above, there would be no video whatsoever. If you provided alternative formats inside `source`, IE would eventually find the one it can handle and would play it instead.